# NullReferenceException only when using dynamic dll linking?

Tags: c#, com, wrapper, nullreferenceexception, ole

I developed a COM-Visible wrapper dll in c# to connect to financial accounting software via dynamic linking. Its Sage 100 Version 90. My main software developed in powerscript (Appeon PowerBuilder) is using my c# wrapper dll via ole connection which itself connects to the financial accounting software interface by dynamic instantiating.

Heres my problem:
If the c# wrapper dll is using dynamic instances like this:

```
dynamic goEngine;
string oleObj = "OLSysEngine90.OLEngine";
Type sageOle = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(oleObj);
goEngine = Activator.CreateInstance(sageOle);
goEngine.exampleFunction...
```

I get random NullReferenceException when using functions of the goEngine class.
But if I don't use dynamic instances by doing static references from the c# wrapper to the financial accounting software dlls like this:

```
using OLSysIInterop90;
using OLReweIBuchung90;
...
...
Engine goEngine;
goEngine = new Engine();
goEngine.exampleFunction...
```

I dont get random failures.

Whats the difference?

TIA

Comment: dynamic does IDispatch black magic to accomplish miracles. Difficult to say, it really depends on your code below, type libraries correctness vs implementation (IDispatch vs IUnknown derivates), etc. Without a reproducing sample, we won't be able to help more. That being said, NullReferenceException with a stack frame in your code is a bug that must be fixed, and maybe it will fix everything else.

Comment: I try my best to offer a reproducing sample, the wrapper dll has many lines of code and the error seems to be only appearing, if the main software is using the wrapper. It seems like if I reproduce the behavior of the main software within the c# wrapper so it is independent the dynamic linking as mentioned above leads to no problems.

Comment: dynamic works fine, but it can follow a quite different execution path (IDispatch/"late bound") than IUnknown-derived ("early bound") calls.

Comment: Are there some safety technics to ensure that dynamic doesnt lead to failures? Or some ways to restrict the behavior to the failure and find the reason of the nullreferenceexception? So e. g. I know the line where the error is happening. Its always at the same position. But its only leading to failure in 6 of 10 times when using dynamic.

Comment: A dynamic vs early-bound call failure is a bad smell for your COM object implementation. There are 99% of chances that the problem is on your side. Again, difficult to say w/o reproducing code.